# Mongoid each.with_index not working

Tags: mongoid

I can do this in plain ruby

```
[3,2,1].each.with_index do |e, i|
  p e, i
end

3
0
2
1
1
2
```

But I can't do this with Mongoid:

```
Model.each.with_index do |e, i|
  p e, i
end
```

It fails with

```
undefined method with_index for Array
```

How can I fix this without using this:

```
Model.each_with_index
```

Which does not allow starting index to be set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mongoid 3.1.3, `with_index` method works as expected.

```
puts Mongoid::VERSION

class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
end

User.create([
  { name: 'Harai' },
  { name: 'Sasaki' }
])

User.each.with_index do |u, i|
  puts "#{u.name}, #{i}"
end
```

The above code works like this:

```
$ ruby main.rb
3.1.3
Harai, 0
Sasaki, 1
```

Your problem might be because you are using older version of Mongoid.